# Properties and database columns with different name/casing

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I'm creating my model class as suggested as the strict mode [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#more-strict).

Ex:

```
import { Optional } from 'sequelize';
import { Table, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript';

interface PersonAttributes {
  id: number;
  categoryId: string;
  name: string;
}

interface PersonCreationAttributes extends Optional<PersonAttributes, 'id'> {}

@Table
class Person extends Model<PersonAttributes, PersonCreationAttributes> {}
```

In my database the column holding the `categoryId` actually is `category_id`. How can I set the column name using this kind of model declaration above?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly define all columns as prop in the `Person` class like this:

```js
@Table
class Person extends Model<PersonAttributes, PersonCreationAttributes> {
  @Column({
    field: 'category_id'
  })
  categoryId!: string;
}
```

See [the advanced example here](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript-example)